# How to run a script locally

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display XML in an HTML page

```
    <html>
<body>
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
document.write("<tr><td>Author</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr><tr><td>Song</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It works like a charm in W3School Try it yourself section, but I want to run it from my local computer, how can i do this?

Comment: Do you have a file called cd_catalog.xml on your local computer?

Comment: Have you read the W3schools tutorial on the subject? Did you understand it all fully? Do you know what this script does?

Comment: Yes I have the cd_catalog.xml and I understand what it does, more ore less I have a problem with running the script, do I need an apache server? or just a browser? I dont really have experience with scripts and how to execute them

Comment: @LeviD77 - You do not need any servers installed as this is all client-side, you just need to copy this all into notepad, save it as html, make sure the xml file is saved in the same location as your html(based on your current code) and it will run

Comment: what error you getting in the console?

Comment: I'm just getting a blank page and the code after pressing CTRL+U

Comment: Are you using Internet Explorer? Can you run the browser's developer tools and debug the script, I think you may be getting an "Access Is Denied" error on this line: xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/lszekely/Desktop/cd_catalog.xml. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. display_table.html:14
(anonymous function) display_table.html:14
Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/Users/lszekely/Desktop/cd_catalog.xml'. display_table.html:14
(anonymous function)

Comment: I used firefox, everything worked, thanks a lot guys :))))